# What should be the value of ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG?

Tags: apache-kafka

We are using Transactions for spring kafka producer (kafka version 2.8).
What is the right value to be set for `ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG`?

Based on a few internet page reads we have set a constant value for each service and getting the below exception.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/discussions/2015

> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send;
> nested exception is
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException:
> There is a newer producer with the same transactionalId which fences the current one.

Appreciate your input on this.

Answer (score 2):

The `ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG` is not controlled by Spring for Apache Kafka, so you need to be sure to set it as unique per your producer instance:

https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/

> We solve the problem of zombie instances by requiring that each transactional producer be assigned a unique identifier called the transactional.id. This is used to identify the same producer instance across process restarts.

So, the point is that every new instance your connect to Kafka broker must have its own `transactional.id`. Same instance may reuse the value after restart.

Comment: Thank you much for your reply. Can we use UUID? We are using Kubernetes for deployment and not much sure on the strategy to provide unique id for each pod.

Comment: @Tech_Dummy You can use k8s downward API to get a pod id as an env-var... Otherwise, yes, a UUID can work

Comment: UUID was giving issues upon restarts at times.. ( Not having error handy). TransactionIdPrefix as per the below post seems to be solving issue for someone. any idea on this? Most of the times these issues are sporadic and so asking for the advice,  https://medium.com/@milo.felipe/spring-boot-kafka-transactions-producerfencedexception-6595623d1bd1